# How to get files from s3 and zip it before download

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on .net core web API and wanting to get the files from s3 and zip before download.
Can you point me to the right direction? I searched the web and couldn't find a solution.

so this block of code is able to read from s3 files (the bucket may contain different types of files), I just dont know how to zip all of them before download

```
public async Task GetFilesAsync(string projectId)        {
        string bucketName = "MyBucket";
        ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucketName
        };

        ListObjectsResponse response = await _client.ListObjectsAsync(request);
        var item = response.S3Objects;

        foreach (var objt in item)
        {
            GetObjectRequest request1 = new GetObjectRequest();
            request1.BucketName = bucketName;
            request1.Key = objt.Key;

            GetObjectResponse Response = await _client.GetObjectAsync(request1);

           //HOW TO ZIP all of the files here and download as single file
            using (Stream responseStream = Response.ResponseStream)
            {
               // Response.WriteResponseStreamToFile("downloadLocation" + "\\" + objt.Key);
            }

        }
}
```

I'm trying this solution but cannot make it work:

```
using (var compressedFileStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Create an archive and store the stream in memory.
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(compressedFileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, false))
    {
        foreach (var caseAttachmentModel in item)
        {
            //Create a zip entry for each attachment
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(caseAttachmentModel.Key);

            //Get the stream of the attachment
            using (var originalFileStream = new MemoryStream(caseAttachmentModel.Body))
            using (var zipEntryStream = zipEntry.Open())
            {
                //Copy the attachment stream to the zip entry stream
                originalFileStream.CopyTo(zipEntryStream);
            }
        }

        return new FileContentResult(compressedFileStream.ToArray(), "application/zip") { FileDownloadName = "Filename.zip" };
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error? WHY this do not work?

Comment: invalid zip file

Comment: What do you mean by "get the files from s3 and zip before download"?

Comment: @samantha07 Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/50516205/5233410

Comment: @samantha07 move the return statement outside of the zipArchive using block. zip file is invalid because you are grabbing the content before archive has written everything to the stream.